# how does android find location coordinates

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm have made a simple app to get the current coordinates of my location using a very simple code

```
public Location getLocation() {
    lm = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    GPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    network = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (!GPS && !network) {
        showsettings();
    } else {
        Log.d("GPSClass", "GPS: " + GPS + " network: " + network);
        this.canGetLocation = true;
        if (network) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
            Log.d("GPSClass", "network");
            location = lm
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {

                return location;
            }
        }
        if (GPS) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
            Log.d("GPSClass", "GPS");
            location = lm
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                return location;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

This works great but i am unable to understand how.
I mean even with my gps switched of and all wifi and network disconnected i am able to get my correct coordinates. How is my device giving me the correct coordinates(even in flight mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
getLastKnownLocation
```

> Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location
>   fix obtained from the given provider.

So if the provider had in the past acquired a valid location it will return this location

Comment: thnx. i don't know how i missed that

Answer (score 0):

I've written a full location services helper class on my blog with all code included if that helps. Check it out and let me know.

http://www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog/android-location-services/